# Filtrar por campos según condición PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Realizo un formulario en el cual muestro los registros de los inmuebles que dieron de alta cada una de las inmobiliaria, debe de limitarse a que solo vea sus propios inmuebles (por el campo **inmobiliaria**) en este caso es el **ID 7**, coloco la condición y efectivamente solo me muestra los que dio de alta la mobiliaria pero al realizar la búsqueda por los campos: **inmobiliaria_name', 'colonia', 'direccion', 'ubicacion', 'zona', 'inmueble_name', 'expediente'**
realiza una busqueda  general en toda la tabla  y *no respeta la condición en este caso solo tendría que buscar por esos campos con el ID de la inmobiliaria.*

[image: CODIGO]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
    if($action == 'ajax'){
        // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
         $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
          $aColumns = array('inmobiliaria_name', 'colonia', 'direccion', 'ubicacion', 'zona', 'inmueble_name', 'expediente');//Columnas de busqueda
         $sTable = "v_inventario_inmueble_completo ";
         $sWhere = "where inmobiliaria = 7";
        if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }
        $sWhere.=" order by id desc";
         include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
        //pagination variables
        $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
        $per_page = 8; //how much records you want to show
        $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        //Count the total number of row in your table*/
        $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
        $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
        $numrows = $row['numrows'];
        $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
        $reload = './expences.php';
         $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($query === false) {
            die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_errror($con));
        }
        //loop through fetched data
       
            
            ?>
```

**Este es el siguiente codigo que de la misma forma quiero que respete la condición inmobiliaria_inmobiliaria = 7**

```html
<?php
$users = [];
if (
    !empty($_GET["estatus_id"])
    || !empty($_GET["kind_id"])
    || !empty($_GET["priority_id"])
    || !empty($_GET["start_at"])
    || !empty($_GET["finish_at"])
) {
    $sql = "select * from v_cita_completo ";
    $where = [];
    if (!empty(["estatus_id"])) {
        $where[] = "estatus_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["estatus_id"]) ."'";
    }

    if (!empty(["kind_id"])) {
        $where[] = "kind_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["kind_id"]) . "'";
    }


    if (!empty($_GET["priority_id"])) {
        $where[] = " priority_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["priority_id"]) . "'";
    }



    if (!empty($_GET["start_at"]) && !empty($_GET["finish_at"])) {
        $where[] = "created_at BETWEEN '"
            . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["start_at"])
            . " 00:00:00' AND '"
            . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["finish_at"])
            . " 23:59:59'"
        ;
    }
    if (count($where) > 0) {
        $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    }
    $users = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

} else {
    $users = mysqli_query($con, "select * from v_cita_completo  where inmobiliaria_inmobiliaria = 7");
}
if ($users === false) {
    die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}



if(@mysqli_num_rows($users)>0){
                                // si hay reportes
                                $_SESSION["report_data"] = $users;
                            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas iniciar el filtro con el dato de la inmobiliaria que se está manejando. En tu código pusiste directamente el número, pero también puede provenir de una variable proporcionada en URL

```
// Forzar a que se muestre la inmobiliaria deseada
$sWhere = "WHERE inmobiliaria = 7";
if($_GET['q'] != '') {
    // En vez de reiniciar la cadena de filtro
    // agrega el resto de condiciones, entre paréntesis
    $sWhere .= " AND (";
    for($i=0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%$q%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
$sWhere.=" ORDER BY id DESC";
```

El resultado será algo como (sin los saltos de línea):

```
WHERE inmobiliaria = 7 AND (
    columna1 LIKE '%cadena%'
    OR columna2 LIKE '%cadena%'
    OR columna3 LIKE '%cadena%'
) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciono muy bien.... tengo otro formulario (busca por fechas y campos)que prácticamente necesito que haga lo mismo, igual le coloco la condición pero al buscar muestra todo.... ¿Me podrías ayudar a notar que es lo que estoy haciendo mal o tendria que generar otra pregunta?

Comment: @Carlos, sí, de preferencia crea otra pregunta.

Comment: entiendo @Triby aunque ya coloque el codigo que te mecionaba, de igual forma genero otro pregunta :)